# Why is independence of representation a sufficient property to not cause contradictions when defining sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be a set and $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Then the set $$X/\sim{}:=\{[x] \ | \ x \in X\}$$ is the set of all equivalence classes with $[x]:= \{y \in X \ | \ y \sim x\}$. It is now possible to define sets such as $Y \subseteq X/\sim{}$ via some property $P$, for example $$Y:=\{[y] \ | \ P(y), y \in X\}.$$ If this property $P$ is not independent of the choice of representation, this would lead to contradictions regarding set membership and is a well defined set. If, however, $P$ is a property that is independent, why does this not lead to
**any** contradictions at all? What I mean is, what guarantees, that there can't be any contradictions whenever $P$ is an independent property.

An easy example might be $Y \subseteq \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ with $Y:=\{[z] \ | \ z \ \mathrm{even} \ \}.$

Comment: We don't do it to avoid contradictions; contradictions aren't a worry if our set theory is consistent. It's just that if $P$ is not independent of choice of representative, then we get funny behavior that we don't like for a lot of applications.

Comment: Actually, the situation you describe is not problematic. It is easy to construct $\{[y]\mid P(y), y \in X\}$ for any property $P$. For example, if $P(z) = z\text{ is a multiple of }3$, then we have the set

$$\{[y] \mid P(y), y \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{[0], [3], [6], [9], \ldots\} = \{[0],[1]\} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: @MaliceVidrine If $P$ wasn't independent and $x \sim y$ but $P(X)$ is true and $P(Y)$ is false lead to a contradiction? Because in that case $[x] \in Y$ but $[y] \notin [Y]$ despite $[x]=[y]$.

Comment: @MaxH - That's not actually true. The thing to notice here is that in your $Y$, there is a suppressed existential quantifier binding the $y$ in the definition. If $x\sim y$, $P(x)$ and $\neg P(y)$, then $[x]=[y]\in Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose isn't to avoid a contradiction, which we presume not to be an issue since we presume our set theory to be consistent. It's just to avoid behaviors we don't want. Notice that the set you call $Y$ exists by the ZF axioms no matter what $X,\sim,P$ are, so ZF (and much weaker theories) would be inconsistent if we could get a contradiction from choosing any combination of these.

To see why there's no inconsistency if the predicate does not respect the equivalence relation, define the equivalence relation $m\sim n$ on $\mathbb{N}$ to be $m=m$; that is, it's the total equivalence relation. Now consider $Y=\{[n]\;|\;n\in\mathbb{N}, n\textrm{ is even}\}$. This is a perfectly good set that poses no logical problems. Why?

Note that in the definition of $Y$, $n$ is actually *bound*. So what is it bound by? The answer is there's a suppressed existential quantifier when you start unpacking the set builder notation, because what it means for $Y$ to have this definition is that
$$x\in Y\Leftrightarrow\exists n(x=\{z\in\mathbb{N}\;|\;n\sim z\}\wedge n\in\mathbb{N}\wedge n\textrm{ is even}).$$
So $Y$ will contain our single equivalence class, even though our condition "$n\textrm{ is even}$" certainly doesn't respect the equivalence relation, because "$n\textrm{ is even}$" is true of *some* $n$ in the equivalence class.

**Edit:**

To elaborate a little more, your worry only holds if it's true (as it appears you're tacitly supposing in your comments) that $$P(x)\Leftrightarrow [x]\in Y,$$
but this is actually equivalent to the supposition that $P$ respects the equivalence relation. For suppose that this biconditional is true, that $x\sim y$, and $[x]\in Y$; then $[y]\in Y$, so our biconditional tells us that $P(y)$. Hence under this assumption, $$P(x)\wedge x\sim y\Rightarrow P(y)$$ holds. That invariance of $P$ under $\sim$ implies $P(x)\Leftrightarrow [x]\in Y$ is trivial.

So this doesn't directly answer your question (which becomes, ultimately, whether our set theory is consistent), but I hope addressing the misconception in the question makes that seem less pressing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I meant with contradiction was not necessarily a logical contradiction but rather that I was worried that it is not a well defined set (I use naive set theory, so I don't really know what this means). What I learned is that $x$ is in the set $\{x \ | \ \phi(x)\}$ iff $x$ satsifies $\phi(x)$. Thus it should be contradictory by this logic. If what you are saying is correct, then it does make sense, however. Do you have a good book/online notes that define set builder notation the way you did it? Thanks!

Comment: @MaxH It's true that $y\in \{x\;|\;\phi(x)\}$ iff $\phi(y)$, but it does *not* follow from this that $y\in\{[x]\;|\;\phi(x)\}$ iff $\phi(y)$, because $[x]$ is not the same thing as the variable $x$. I don't know of a modern book that spells out how to unpack set-builder notations, but you can work it out for yourself by considering how you would claim that $Y$ if you weren't allowed to write a set-builder for it. How do you say that a member of something is an equivalence class?